# Magento how to add slick slider into magento cms pages

Tags: magento

I have used default rwd theme. Please suggest how to add slick slider into magento cms pages.

Please help.

Comment: I used the information on the following link and it worked for me
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/how-to-apply-slick-slider-to-magento